# How can I assign input A or input B to the same command

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to make a light inventory system for some practice to attempt to get better in C#, I am showing my user a range of metals and asking them what they would like to do
(expecting the result "take metal" or "pick up metal")

How would I go around doing this?

I am currently doing

```
If UserInput = "Pick up metal" or "take metal" then invt=worth.metal
```

However, this does not work, the script for some reason crashes saying I am attempting to set "take metal" as a boolean

I could solve this by doing two separate lines

```
(If input = "pick up metal" invt = worth.metal
if input = "take metal" invt = worth.metal)
```

However this would over complicate the code when I get to accepting 10+ user inputs.

Comment: Put up some code and also please avoid `does not work` and specify what is the issue. What is the exception you are getting.

Comment: Is this C# or VB? Provide real code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the equality checking operator is `==`, not `=`. The second one is the assignment operator. Secondly, you can perform two checks using the `||` (short-circuit OR) operator. Try:

```
If (UserInput == "Pick up metal" || UserInput == "take metal")
{
    // do what you need
}
```

I assume that `UserInput` is a string variable. By the way, the code you presented doesn't look like valid C# to me.

Comment: Why not use the `.Equal()` method instead of the `==` operator ?

Comment: @CoderofCode I'm guessing that `UserInput` is a string. Should probably clarify that.